# Get Monitor Coordinates and Resolution / Multiple Monitors

Tags: c#, multiple-monitors

I want to get the coordiantes and resolution of each screen. I currently use:

```
foreach (Screen screen in Screen.AllScreens) {

    Rectangle bounds = screen.Bounds;

    float displayScale = screen.Primary ? 1f : 1.25f;

    bounds.Width = (int)(bounds.Width * displayScale);
    bounds.Height = (int)(bounds.Height * displayScale);
    bounds.X = 0;
    bounds.Y = 0;

    Console.WriteLine(screen.Bounds + " => " + bounds);

    g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(220, 0, 0, 0)), 5f), bounds);
}
```

Output:

```
{X=0,Y=0,Width=1920,Height=1080} => {X=0,Y=0,Width=1920,Height=1080}
{X=-3840,Y=-941,Width=3072,Height=1728} => {X=0,Y=0,Width=3840,Height=2160}
```

The problem is, that I can't draw on negative coordinates. Also, I want to get the scaling factor of the monitor automatically.

This is what i expected:
[Screenshot with screen order and Coordiantes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzdLr.png)